# How to Count Rows in a Separate Table Using a Foreign Key

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, oracle-11g

I am in school to become a software engineer, and I am taking my first class on SQL. We usually use MsSQL, but the schools VMWare instance is down, so I have an older version of Oracle on my computer (Oracle 11g Express). I am trying to take my customer table, and orderInfo table to get the count of each customers # of orders. I have it working if I use the orderTable, but then it would not get customers that have 0 orders. Basically, if the customer is not in the orderInfo table, they won't have an order count. Please See the table structure below and my SQL code.

Customer Table
[image: Customer Table]
Order Info Table
[image: OrderInfo Table]

This is my current SQL code and the output.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(ORDERINFO.ORDER_ID) AS TotalOrders
FROM ORDERINFO
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Output:
[image: Output of SQL code]

Thank you so much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A join of some type between the two tables is needed - and then group by `customers.customer_id`. Then to get results for customers with no orders, one way would be to use a `LEFT` join:

```
SELECT 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID, 
    COUNT(O.ORDER_ID) AS TotalOrders
FROM 
        CUSTOMERS  C 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ORDERINFO  O
    ON 
        O.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY 
    C.CUSTOMER_ID ;
```